# Creation of nxn matrix - sudoku like

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I am working on a problem, where I need to create a NxN matrix(N is given as input here), such that, all entries are in the range [1,N] and no entry is repeated twice in a particular row or column. There are no constraints on diagonals.

Also, I need to use a random number generator to ensure the output of the grid changes with every execution.

Also, I was given a hint as to use backtracking to solve this.

I had thought of an algorithm as follows

```
func(i,j):
    grid[i][j] = 1 + rand()%N
    if(check(grid)==true)
        j++
        if j == N
            j = 0
            i++
            if i == N
                return
    else
       //resetting the grid entry
        grid[i][j] = -1;
    //make a recursive call to func(i,j) again
    func(i,j)
```

check(grid) returns true if no element is repeated twice any row/column.

I know this is incorrect as it might get stuck in an infinite loop somewhere and also I am not using backtracking in this
Can someone guide me as to how to use backtracking for my given problem?

It would be nice if someone could provide some code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's pseudocode (which is essentially [Knuth's "Algorithm X"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X), specialized for this problem) that generates a random Latin square:

```
complete(S):
    If S is completely filled in, return true
    find the index [i,j] where there's the fewest immediate choices.
    for c in each choice for S[i,j] {  // iterated over in a random order
        S[i][j] = c
        if complete(S) {
            return true
        }
    }
    S[i][j] = blank
    return false
}
```

This procedure completes the array S with a random valid solution if there is one, returning a bool describing whether a solution exists. It can return any possible solution.

Note that in this procedure a "choice" for an empty cell is a number that doesn't immediately cause a problem -- that is, any number that doesn't already appear in that row and column.

There's various optimizations you can do to make this faster (one easy example: passing an extra parameter that counts how many blank cells remain), but [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links](http://Dancing%20Links) is Knuth's efficient solution.

Another cheap solution, that doesn't generate all Latin squares is simply to permute another Latin square: permuting the rows, columns and numbers of a Latin square yields another Latin square. So you could have 10 or 20 different latin squares baked into your program, pick one at random, and then disguise it by permuting it.

Here's a reasonably efficient Python solution. It generates a random 30x30 Latin square in approximately half a second. It should still be possible to improve the speed by a factor of N/logN by eliminating the O(N^2) max operation and instead maintaining a priority queue, but it's probably already fast enough.

```
import random

def bitcount(n):
    i = 0
    while n:
        i += 1
        n &= n-1
    return i

def complete(S, rowset, colset, entries):
    N = len(S)
    if entries == N * N:
        return True
    i, j = max(
        ((i, j) for i in xrange(N) for j in xrange(N) if S[i][j] == 0),
        key=(lambda (i, j): bitcount(rowset[i]|colset[j])))
    bits = rowset[i]|colset[j]
    p = [n for n in xrange(1, N+1) if not (bits >> (n-1)) & 1]
    random.shuffle(p)
    for n in p:
        S[i][j] = n
        rowset[i] |= 1 << (n-1)
        colset[j] |= 1 << (n-1)
        if complete(S, rowset, colset, entries+1): return True
        rowset[i] &= ~(1 << (n-1))
        colset[j] &= ~(1 << (n-1))
    S[i][j] = 0
    return False

N = 30
ns = len(str(N))
for _ in xrange(5):
    S = [[0] * N for _ in xrange(N)]
    assert complete(S, [0]*N, [0]*N, 0)
    for row in S:
        print ''.join('%*d ' % (ns, x) for x in row)
    print
```